# cryptsetup luksFormat error: access denied or device doesnt exist

Tags: partitioning, encryption

I am trying to initialize the LUKS encryption on a usb stick partition. 
I'm on ubuntu. partition size is 43.7gb

I have double checked with `fdisk -l` that the partition I'm trying to access exists: `/dev/sdb3`; I tried use flag `-y` instead; and `sudo`.

It gives me an error when I run `cryptsetup --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/sdb3`:

```
Device /dev/sdb3 doesn't exist or access denied.`
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing here

`df -h` output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 58.3 GiB, 62579015680 bytes, 122224640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x77e6cfe3
```

`fdisk -l /dev/sdb` output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 58.3 GiB, 62579015680 bytes, 122224640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x77e6cfe3
```

Comment: Could you paste result of commands `df -h` and `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`?

Comment: Since you're asking what you may be missing let's go through the important things (again): what's the output of `sudo blkid /dev/sdb3` and did you run `cryptsetup` as super-user (e. g. with `sudo`)?

Comment: yes i was running it as su; blkid gives  no output

Comment: @dylan Please post the full outputs of `df -h` and `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`.

Comment: I suspect that there's simply no `/dev/sdb3`. What's the output of `ls -l /dev/sdb3`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster yes i think you are right, it states "no such file directory"... but output for `fdisk -l` does list `/dev/sdb3`  Thats why I got confused

Comment: It doesn't according to the listings in your question. In fact, `/dev/sdb` appears to be unpartitioned.

Comment: @DavidFoerster     `/dev/sdb1  *         64  5794271  5794208  2.8G 17 Hidden HPFS/NTFS`        
`/dev/sdb2       5794272  6009311   215040  105M  1 FAT12`        
`/dev/sdb3       6009312 97656250 91646939 43.7G 83 Linux`        sorry i just realized i didn't paste the full output

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: Did you alter the partition table of that drive since the last boot (for internal drives) or reconnection (for external drives)? If not, make sure that none of the (altered) partitions is in use, run `sudo partprobe /dev/sdb` and try `ls -l /dev/sdb3` again.